# Debugar variaveis em mustache

Tags: php, moodle, mustache.js, web-component

Gente o mustache promete fazer maravilhas porem não está sendo meu caso. O moodle é PHP porem os temas agora usam o mustache, porem o código das telas geradas pelo tal do mustache são algo tipo assim:

```
<nav class="list-group m-t-1">
{{/showdivider}}
{{#action}}
<a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action {{#isactive}}font-weight-bold{{/isactive}}" href="{{{action}}}" data-key="{{key}}">
    <div class="m-l-{{get_indent}}">
        {{#is_section}}
            <div class="media">
                <span class="media-left">
                    {{#pix}}i/folder{{/pix}}
                </span>
                <span class="media-body">{{{text}}}</span>
            </div>
        {{/is_section}}
        {{^is_section}}
            {{{text}}}
        {{/is_section}}
    </div>
</a>
{{/action}}
{{^action}}
<div class="list-group-item" data-key="{{key}}">
    <div class="m-l-{{get_indent}}">
        {{#is_section}}
            {{#pix}}i/folder{{/pix}}
        {{/is_section}}
        {{{text}}}
    </div>
</div>
{{/action}}
```

{{/ flatnavigation }}

Quero saber como debugar as variáveis, o que está chegando neste arquivo, por que agora eu preciso alterar e adicionar funcionalidades e eu "acho" que estou enviando certo, mas é realmente como dar um tiro no escuro. Já tentei google mas mustache não encontrei muita cosia que me ajudasse, alguém sabe de algo?

Comment: Ja tentou debugar no PHP e verificar o retorno que é enviado a view?